# reactjs in VSCode: how to find out all scripts that imported component from current script?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm new to using VSCode and the programming language reactjs, so excuse me if this is obvious.  I'm troubled with the following situation:

1. In many reactjs projects, the component defined in a `.js` file is imported in another script under a different name.
2. Sometimes, the component defined in a `.js` file are not even exported with a name. E.g. `export default {...}` or  `export default (...) => {... some code ...}`

How do I find all the occurrences of the component throughout the project in these situations?

What I need is a method or tool that can locate all places where the component is imported/used, since doing a "global search" on the name with "Match Case" and "Match Whole Word" is not useful at all in these situations. 1. It is imported under a different name, so knowing the export name is not useful; 2. It has no name to start the search.

Answer (score 0):

It's the feature of the library react.js that you can export a component by its name or by using the keyword `default`.

1. If you export a component by the keyword 'default' with the name of the component besides default than you can use it in any other script by importing any name e.g `export default AppBar` than `import App from './AppBar'`
2. If you just export the component by not giving it the name than it will be an anonymously exported function which you can named anything while importing it in any other script.

Comment: this does not answer the question. I understand your two points. What I'm asking for is a method or tool that can locate all places that the component is imported or used, since doing a "global search" on the name is not useful at all in these situations

Comment: ok, if you use same name as it is a best practise also and easy to understand later on, not only for you but anyone else programmer who is working on your code. By doing this when you rename your file the code editor will ask from you and then automaticaly find and replace the name in all files where you have imported that file.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what Saima Ashraf already said:

### Naming Components

When you create a React Component, I would highly recommend to give it a name, best practice it is the same name as the file name, for example:

`Navbar.js`

```js
export default Navbar() {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

And in another file you import it with the name you have given it.

```js
// Layout.js

import Navbar from "./Navbar";

export default Layout() {
  return <Navbar />
}
```

When creating new Components, they always should have a descriptive name of what they do.

### How to find the components

#### VS Code

In VS Code on the left sidebar, you have a search function. It is the Magnifying glass Icon. You can write the name of your component and activate the settings "Match Case" and "Match Whole Word". SO if you were to search for "Navbar" you would get all the files that have Navbar used as a word in the file, which is usually the component being used.

#### React Dev Tools

You can also install the React Dev Tool extension on your browser with which you can check out the component tree being used. It also has a search function, so you can search for a specific component like "Navbar".

Comment: What I'm asking for is a method or tool that can locate all places where the component is imported or used, since doing a "global search" on the name with   "Match Case" and "Match Whole Word" is not useful at all in these situations.

Comment: First of all, when creating a new Component, it should be a named component and not anonymous like in your example. That is just bad practice.
Second, I do not think there is a thing to check where a component is being used, the search function is the best source to find them. Granted, you have named your component, as you should.

Answer (score 0):

Put the cursor on the variable name, then press Shift + F12, it will show all the place that this variable is used
If it has no name, for example "export default function (){}", just put the cursor into the word "function"